# How to install Bootstrap Filestyle package in visual stuio?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, jquery-plugins

im newbe, want use that package but didnt know how to add it to my asp.net mvc project, to Improve `<input>`'s look.
Just download the package from here:
http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/
what now? thx.

Answer (score 1):

First of all after downloading the package add the source files in your project.

```
bootstrap-filestyle/src/bootstrap-filestyle.js
bootstrap-filestyle/src/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js
```

You should also have bootstrap `CDN S` added to your poject--

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[After these two steps just follow this documentation to get started](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/)

As starting point try adding below two lines to your code to see how it works.

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false">
<script>
$(":file").filestyle({input: false});
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need just two files from the whole package?